# GWT TextInputCell value change handler

Tags: gwt, celltable

I started using the `CellTable` widget.  I need an editable text cell so I tried `TextInputCell` but to my dismay, I can't find the "value change handler".

How can I get notified when the cell content changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need change handlers for cells. You set a FieldUpdater on your column. It has update() method which fires when value of a cell in this column changes. For example:

```
myEditableColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<T, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, T object, String value) {
        // do something when value changes
    }
});
```